How to access a crosstab measure in the main report
I have a Jaspersoft report (6.17.0) with a crosstab. The crosstab has a measure "minremaining" that provides the minimum of the values across the columns. The crosstab is in a detail band and I want to suppress printing of the band when the value of minremaining is not negative.
If I could access the crosstab measure in the main report then I could use it in the band's "Print When Expression". However, I don't see any way to do that. Any suggestions?
